# Cufflinks (Plotly) Boxplot not showing outliers correctly

Tags: python, graph, plotly, boxplot

Using a data set I am trying to use the

```
DataFrame.iplot(kind='box')
```

which should generate a box plot that allows for interaction.

However it doesn't seem to be working.
Instead of having a line stopping at the first quartile, it instead extends to the minimum value.
Additionally the first quartile is not correct. However the third quartile is correct.
It seems to be having an issue excluding outliers when its calculating.

The images included is the boxplot generated by the above mentioned code as well as an Excel equivalent with the exact same set of data.

Obviously my question is how can I get it to work properly.

The data set is as follows:
hours
[403,
390,
444,
309,
222,
490,
389,
411,
402,
380,
315,
429,
435,
429,
339]

Many thanks

[image: cufflinks boxplot] [image: Excel Boxplot]

Comment: Can you add your dataset or a mock dataset reproducing the observed result? Otherwise it is really hard to help.

Comment: @MaximilianPeters I have added the data set as requested.

Comment: Seems like a bug to me, when using Plotly JS or Python the outlier is correctly identified but the 1st quartile is calculated differently, see https://community.plot.ly/t/boxplot-quartile-seems-wrong/2234

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I faced the same issue, solved it with `boxpoints='outliers'`. In your sample data just one outlier is shown:

```
pd.Series([403, 390, 444, 309, 222, 490, 389,
           411, 402, 380, 315, 429, 435, 429,
           339]).iplot(kind='box', boxpoints='outliers')
```

[image: generated image]